# Negative lookahead in Text.Regex.Posix

Tags: regex, haskell

I am trying to use negative lookahead – standart regex-posix practice:

```
"foobarbaz" =~ "^(?!.*bar).*$" :: Bool
```

and getting error `*** Exception: user error (Text.Regex.Posix.String died: (ReturnCode 13,"repetition-operator operand invalid"))`

How can I use negative lookahead in Haskell?

Comment: POSIX regular expressions do not support zero width assertions. Try using a PCRE package. Alternatively use a negated approach: Check for `bar` and only use lines where it does not match.

Comment: See [Text.Regex.PCRE.Light](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-light-0.4.0.4/docs/Text-Regex-PCRE-Light.html), for example.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: there are too many GREP dialects!

Your original GREP works on InDesign (it uses a slightly amended [`boost`](http://www.boost.org) implementation); so does this alternative:

```
^((?!bar).)*$
```

i.e., try to match `(?!bar).` on each character in turn.